# Meteor Route.go() is keeping all the previous JS code

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I just noticed that when I do Route.go() in Meteor, it keeps all of the previous page's template handlers/events/render JS code.

For example, on the previous page before Route.go(), I had a setInterval(...) running at every x seconds.

After Route.go(), this setInterval continued to fire, however because the required elements were no longer there, it just kept generating errors.

Is this by design? How can I route and start fresh?

**Note: this is true for clicking a link as well, since technically that's a route too (if the link was created as a route)**

Comment: you need to clear your clear your interval. iron router is not responsible for that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using Router.go is not analogous to clicking a hyperlink or issuing a server-side redirect.**

It's common to expect Route.go to act like a non-bound hyperlink (i.e. to physically issue a new GET request), or issue a server-side 301, but that's not how Iron Router works.

It will handle the route *within your current loaded window environment*, typically making use of HTML5 pushState to swap out the URL but handle the route internal to Meteor.

This means any existing setIntervals or other "global" events will continue to run unless you stop the handler explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, can you also tell me what happens to Meteor events? If a template has a bunch of events, they won't carry over to the next route, am I correct? Or do they work the same way as an interval?

Comment: Events are typically attached to the "Template" object which is instantiated on the initial page load, so they remain in memory across routes. You can see this in action by creating a separate <template name="route1"> tag and <template name="route2">, connecting "route1" to /, and then using the browser console to debug Template.route2 -- all helpers and events are available. However, since they're out of "context" of the route, any helpers/events are no longer bound to the "active" / visible template.

Answer (score 1):

If you set an interval with `Meteor.setInterval()`, you have to clear it with `Meteor.clearInterval()` by yourself.

[Check out the doc](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/timers)

Comment: `Meteor.setInterval()` returns a handler, which you have to pass to `Meteor.clearInterval(intervalHandler)`.